# How to Block an UI page from 7pm tp 7am

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an UI page created using html,javascript,jquery,I need to display the UI page only for a certain period of time ie,.. 7am tp 7pm. So after evening 7pm, when i login it should display some message saying the page is blocked due to data transmission. 
How will I go about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using php as well ? because actually its possible with js but this could be turned of easy.

Comment: It'd be quite easy if you are using a framework like ASP.NET MVC. The Controller could do the logic to check the current DateTime. Has your HTML got a server side programming language at all?

Comment: Do this server side. Using client-side code will be to easy to get around.

Comment: Blocking via Javascript is useless.

Comment: if you are using some framework then you can write the logic there. check datatime and redirect to another page accoardingly, you can also check date time in javascript put the logic there, but it will not be safe.

Comment: I'm using spring framework along with this.

Comment: Hi @Dwza I'm not using php

Comment: ok :) than my answere isn't needed. ill delete it :D

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use **Cron** to edit the **.htaccess** file on the server

Answer (score 0):

You can call the following function on click event that will check for the time
access is to be blocked

```
function checkdate()
{
var currentdate = new Date();

var startlimit = new Date(); 

startlimit.setHours(7);
startlimit.setMinutes(0);
startlimit.setSeconds(0);
startlimit.setMilliseconds(0);

var endlimit = startlimit

endlimit.setHours(19);

if( (currentdate < endlimit) && (currentdate > startlimit) )
 {
       //block access
       //show message
 }

return false;
}
```

Comment: As its pointed out in the comments, using JS is not the best idea. This is really not recommended.

Comment: let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: There are 2 problems with this: first, as @Dwza and others have pointed out, it's very simple to get around the block (so, it's probably pointless); and second, if it isn't already pointless, `new Date()` will give the user's computer time.  If you want a uniform time for all users (and you insist on doing it all in js), you will need to get the server time from the Response Header and then apply the logic after that.

Comment: Agreed with @Dwza, you can always initialize the date by passing the hours,minute, seconds from php or any server side language if you want